# Arduino publish Odom

Tags: arduino, navigation, odometry, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Arduino MEGA 2560 can publish odometry values (nav_msgs/Odometry.msg)?

I am using an H-bridge that is connected to arduino and the arduino connected to raspberryPi. I'm using ros_serial communication between arduino and raspbery.

What is advised?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337180/arduino-publish-odom/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can publish any message type from your arduino. You need to write a .ino script to do so.
Make sure you include the following lines:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
```

at the top before the line

```
#include "Arduino.h"
```

**Edit:** The rosserial library even has an example sketch named Odom. You can check it out.

---

Originally posted by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) with karma: 463 on 2019-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on 2019-11-09**:
I was able to implement the arduino odometry, but the rate was very low, around 8 hz.  So I made arduino publish geometry_message / Twist and calculate odometry on a python node in raspberry (got rates around 100hz). I think the nav_message / Odometry message is too much for arduino to process

thanks

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-11-09**:
Yes, it is better to keep arduino scripts light, mostly for input and output, and let main computer handle the computation to be done with that data.